# sending mail to a big list of recipients - PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

I'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question.

Situation:
We have a website and we got feedback that a big part of our users cannot login after registering (1769 out of approx. 12000 users to be exact). We found and fixed the issue however we have to delete all those "shadow accounts" (those who can't log in) from our database, and make them register once again. To do so I created a short script which goes through every single e-mail address and send an e-mail through PHP `mail()` function.

Question:
My concern is whether I can/should use `mail()` function for such a big job. Would I be marked as spammer? Would my web server crash? or is it completely safe to use? Or maybe there are some better solutions for that?

Cheers in advance

Comment: You should use SMTP instead.

Comment: could you explain why mail() function is not good for this? it would be very helpful for me in future.

Comment: Go through this link  [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Are you sending the same email to lots of users?  Or is every email different?  If the former, you only need to call `mail()` once with a large `BCC` list.  If the latter, why are you concerned about being marked as a spammer or crashing?  Who would "mark you as a spammer"?  As for crashing, you can simply execute the script during non-peak hours, perhaps throttling the messages by sending a few and waiting a moment between batches.

Comment: @David The e-mail is the same (except the First/Last Name and e-mail address - of course)

Comment: @TomaszGolinski: Then it's not the same :)

Comment: @David I assume that I can get away without using first and last name

Comment: @TomaszGolinski: If the email subject/body can be the same then sending a single email with a large `BCC` list would certainly address the performance concern, since there'd be only one communication to the SMTP server.

Comment: @David cheers, I will do it that way then as it seems to be the easiest way.